# ProcessStartInfo.Arguments - Constants

Tags: c#, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to call a supplied command line batch tool program. Trial and error has taken me to `ProcessStartInfo`... The problem is the arguments need to be constants. I had been collecting paths and file names to be used in the arguments. How can I use variables in the arguments?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "sbsmutator.exe";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Allegorithmic\Substance\\BatchTools\1.x\";
startInfo.Arguments = " specialization --input " + templatePath + " --presets-path " + resourcesPath +
                    " --output-name " + name +
                    " --output-graph-name " + RemoveSpaces(name) +
                    " --output-path " + sbsPath;
```

Comment: What's wrong with the variables above? Any error?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You want to know how to use variables in your arguments, but you're using `" --output-name " + name`. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: There's a double `\\\` for the directory separator between Substance and BatchTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You contradict yourself in the question by stating you need to use constants yet ask how to use variables - they're diametrically opposed as far as the ideas go. One is constant the other is variable. Currently you use literals to construct your inputs, so you can swap them out easily enough.

If you want to use constants for the receiving process's arguments, then, for example, do:

```
const string ProcessExe = "sbsmutator.exe";
const string OutputName = "--output-name";
```

And string them together, or use `string.Format` and such:

```
startInfo.FileName = ProcessExe;
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", OutputName, SomeOtherConstant);
```

And so on.

Using variables would be very similar, only it likely doesn't make sense to have such things as alterable reusables.